# Trying to send a message to the client in python3 using python shell but still get an error

Tags: python-3.x

```
client.send('knock')
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File 'stdin', line 1, in                                             TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: I assume you are trying to send a "message" instead of a "massage".

Comment: yeah typing error bro

Answer (score 1):

In python 3 strings are Unicode but when transmitting on the network it needs to be bytes string that is why this error is raising. So there are couple of ways to do so

```
my_message = 'any_message'
client.send(my_message.encode('utf-8'))
```

**Or**

```
client.send(b'knock')
```